# Multiple signals arriving at handler

Tags: c, signals, sigaction

I have a main process that has forked some kid processes.

Each kid does something and blocks itself. By blocking itself every child sends a `SICHLD` signal to the parent process.

I also have declared a `sigaction` action, in the main process code, in order to catch the `SIGCLHD` that the kids will send.

```
static struct sigaction action;
action.sa_handler = handler 
sigfillset(&(action.sa_mask));
sigaction(SIGCHLD, &action, NULL);
```

The `SIGCHLD` handler when called, checks which kid sent the `SIGCHLD` signal and does something for that kid.

The question is, what happens if multiple kids send signals at the same time? Let's say that kid(1) sent `SIGCHLD`. The handler catches it and before he completes the handle, kid(2) and kid(3) both send signals. Will the handler run for each of these signals after he is done with kid(1) or will these signals get ignored?

Comment: check [Second signal call in sighandler - what for?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17728463/1673391)

Answer (score 0):

`SIGCHLD` is somewhat special in that you get exactly one signal per exiting child; these signals are tied to the corresponding zombies/wait-status left behind by the child processes they correspond to. But in general most signals are just flags, not queues. If possible it's best not to use `SIGCHLD` and instead just use `waitpid` and track child exit in some other way (e.g. by observing EOF status on a pipe from the child in your `poll` loop or such).

Comment: The kid process does not exit when it does it's job, it just changes state to "stopped". I am already using waitpid in order to see which kid changed state to "stopped".

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure of the exact rules for stopping but I think they're the same, except possibly in the case where the stopped process resumes before the signal is able to be delivered...